# How to find the current number of https connections to IIS?

Tags: iis, performance-monitoring, iis-8.5, performance-counters, google-analytics

I recently enabled https for my site https://cooltext.com that runs on IIS.

I'd like to know how many of my users are using https vs http. Google is directing search users to the https site, but most users are hitting http from some link or by typing in the address.

I searched thru the windows performance counters but couldn't find any. Did I miss a counter somewhere? Perhaps connection count by port number somewhere in there?

I checked google analytics but couldn't find any tracking on http vs https.

How can I find this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at perfmon, but also did not see anything to distinguish between HTTP & HTTPS. For "current" connections you could use `netstat` or other network analyzer tool. For "trends" you could use one of many weblog analyzer tools to review the IIS log files. Look at the field named "s-port".

```
Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
Version: 1.0
Date: 2016-09-10 03:47:52
Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port
2016-09-10 03:47:52 1.2.3.4 GET / - 80
2016-09-10 03:47:52 1.2.3.4 GET / - 443
```

Powershell

```
(netstat -n | where {$_ -match "\d:443\s"} | measure-object).count
0
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. Turns out 30% of my users are on https now.